# How to query efficiently and often the Room database with ViewModel and LiveData?

Tags: android, android-room, android-viewmodel

**Edit:** What I'm essentialy asking.

In SQLite I could create a cursor out of my query like this:

```
 Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, searchClause, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

Where I could pass different columns, searchClauses or selectionArgs to pinpoint the data I want with my query.

What is the equivalent of this with Room Database??

**Edit 2:** Furthermore, if I query the database I would receive a list with all items stored in the database. From there I want to create another list that amalgamates items into another list. For example if I have three items of colour blue in the database, I want to show a listitem with the item "blue" that also shows the average of selling price across these 3 items. The new list would thus consist of all colour items, amalgamated into one list item for each colour, with their respective averages in selling price.

How would I go about doing that?

---

Ok, so I have a rather big database with 50 columns for my app. Most columns can take a variety of values that are defined by user input.

I will display this data throughout my app in various fragments (in the same activity), using listViews in them.

So my initial approach would have been to ask a lot, but small queries of Room, to get the data I need where I need it. 
However, I'm stuck at how to make many of these queries when using the ViewModel/LiveData architecture.

**For example in my Dao this could be a query:**

```
@Query("SELECT selling_price FROM table WHERE colour IN (:colours)")
LiveData<List<Shoe>> getColour(String[] colours);
```

I would use this when I want to make a list that shows the colours and avg. selling price for example. A list item could either have one item (e.g. Blue) or two or more colours combined (Black and Yellow), so that's why I need to use a String[]. (My app isn't about shoes/colours I'm just using this as an example)..

To reach this query I would have to set up a **ViewModel with a Factory** right?
Like so:

```
public class ArrayViewModel extends ViewModel {


private LiveData<List<Shoe>> colourList;
private final String[] mColours;

public ArrayViewModel(Database dataBase, String[] colours){

    mColours = colours;
    colourList = dataBase.shoeDao().getColours(actions);

}


public LiveData<List<Shoe>> getColours(){return colourList;}

public static class ArrayViewModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

    private final Database mDatabase;
    private final String [] mColours;

    public ArrayViewModelFactory(Database dataBase, String[] colours) {

        mDatabase = dataBase;
        this.mColours = colours;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        return (T) new ArrayViewModel(mDatabase, mColours);
    }
}
```

}

**I would then query the data** in my Activity or Fragment like this. I'd have to pass my defined colour[] with the colours I want to query into the factory.

```
 ArrayViewModel.ArrayViewModelFactory factory = new ArrayViewModel.ArrayViewModelFactory(database,color[])
    final ArrayViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,factory).get(ArrayViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getColours().observe(this, new Observer<List<Shoe>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Shoe> shoes) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
```

This is were **my problem/question** lies:

If I want to query "blue" for my first list item. And the {"black","yellow"} for my second, and then other colours for my third list item. Would I have to make a new factory each time, and then set the new factory on the ViewModel?
a
How else could I retrieve this data? And this is only a small example: sometimes I want to have the avg. selling price listed by shoe size. Sometimes I want to query the most popular shoe sizes by colour.

My real database has 50 columns with loads of different potential queries which all need a different amount/type of arguments passed. How could I make all these queries to the populate different listViews/RecyclerViews with it? It can't be that I have to make a new factory each time and create dozens of ViewModels to allow for each argument type and count that is passed? Or is this like creating a new Cursor for each query in SQLite?

Bascially I'm at a loss how to make that many queries with Room.

**My alternative Idea:**

Instead of making hundreds of small queries (if I figure out how to do it), I thought I would just query the database once and getAllData with my ViewModel. This would give me a list with all data.

From there I could just run/filter through the list in a for loop, to look for what I want?

For example:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < allShoesList.size(); i++ ){

        Shoe shoe= allShoesList.get(i);

        String colour = hand.getColour();

        //make different lists according to Colour
        switch (colour){

            case "blue":              
                blueList.add(shoe);
                break;

            case "black":
                blackList.add(shoe);
                break;

               ...

        }

    }
```

I could then get these lists from the Activity via getter methods in the corresponding adapters and then do further operations there? Like getting average shoe size or average selling price separated by colour and then display these averages in a list?

Basically, I'm not sure how to approach fetching all that data into multiple list views, when I only need very specific data in each listView, and never all data.

Comment: can you sum up what you are trying to do with one sentence?

Comment: Fetching data via lots of small queries from Room database. Queries could have lots of arguments to be passed in. Would I have to create a new ViewModel Factory for each of these queries?

Comment: I made an edit at the very top to show better what I'm essentially asking. Basically, how can I ask queries in a relative dynamic way and often.

Comment: You can't create dynamic query through the database Dao but you could  get a reference to the RoomDatabase and use its query() method.

Comment: I'm trying that, but it seems that I would have to wrap every query into a LiveData observer individually? I'm looking for an option to just change the arguments of a query, while using the same ViewModel or LiveData or observer. 
That is, I can do object.getColours(myString[]).observe. And then receive the list in the observe method. But I then want to do the exact same query with a different String[]. To do that would I have to make a new Observer? I feel this would get out of hand with all the threads that this creates.

Comment: I made a further Edit (Edit 2) to explain what I really want to do.

Comment: If you use the query() method you lose the support of the database to provide you with a LiveData. So you'll need to query the database yourself and requery() the database when you know it has changed. Wrapping the query() result in a LiveData will not magically help you to get the previous observer status.The example you posted its quite easy to do with Room and obtain a LiveData: *SELECT color, avg(price) FROM theTable GROUP BY color* .To be honest, I don't understand why you don't post your exact requirements and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to developing and the concept of LiveData is still somewhat difficult to understand. Thus it's also quite difficult for me to post the exact requirements. 

Unfortunately, I can't use group by, because an item could technically be part of more than one group, so it gets quite difficult. The colour example I provided wasn't quite adequate, as then GROUP BY would be a great solution. 

Anyway, I think I might be best off using many queries in this case and just run them on a different Runnable thread without using live data.